# Try to figure out "target dose" from DoseFinding package

Tags: r, package

I tried to run the codes to figure out target dose and D optimally
but it always say my length is wrong.  I do not understand how to code "weights"
and delta.  Can someone help me out here?
Here is my code:

```
library(DoseFinding)
doses <- c(0,5, 25, 125, 200)
fmodels <- Mods(linear = NULL, emax = 14,
            doses = doses, placEff=-0.17, maxEff=-1.4)



weights <- rep(1/5, 5)

desTD <- optDesign(fmodels, probs=1, designCrit="TD&Dopt",Delta=0.5)
plot(fmodels, plotTD = TRUE, Delta = 0.2)
```

---

When I used the example it showed all the probabilities for all doses:

---

```
data(IBScovars)

doses <- c(0, 10, 25, 50, 100, 150)
fmodels <- Mods(linear = NULL, emax = 25, exponential = 85,
            logistic = c(50, 10.8811),
            doses = doses, placEff=0, maxEff=0.4)
plot(fmodels, plotTD = TRUE, Delta = 0.2)
weights <- rep(1/4, 4)
desTD <- optDesign(fmodels, weights, Delta=0.2, designCrit="TD")
```

---

```
Calculated TD - optimal design:
      0      10      25      50     100     150 
0.34960 0.09252 0.00366 0.26760 0.13342 0.15319
```

---

But for mine only three doses show up...does it mean
other doses are not important?

Comment: Thanks for your input, Mr. Flick
When I run everything it shows this
    Calculated TD - optimal design:
          0      25     200 
    0.27727 0.36693 0.35579 

is 0 25 200 are the target dose for optimal design??
so we only need those three doses ?
and below is the probabilities right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the help page, you need to have the same number of weights as doses. The models retain info about the doses used. What you have looks fine, but you could also do

```
ds <- attr(fmodels, "doses")
weights <- rep.int(1, length(ds))/length(ds)
```

to extract the info from the `fmodel` object.

Also, when running your `optDesign` function, i had problem with the `probs` and `dsignCrit` parameters you specified. The `probs` length should correspond to the length of `fmodels`. An interal calculation does this to find the total length

```
Reduce("+",lapply(fmodels, function(x) {
    if (is.vector(x)) 
        return(1)
    if (is.matrix(x)) 
        return(nrow(x))
}))
# [1] 2
```

so there should be two probabilities. Also i think `designCrit="TD&Dopt"` should be `designCrit="Dopt&TD"` so the following seems to run without error

```
desTD <- optDesign(fmodels, probs=c(.5,.5), 
    weights=weights, designCrit="Dopt&TD",Delta=0.5)
```

It's unclear exactly what your question about `Delta` is. According to the help page, that's just your estimated effect size.

Comment: thanks for your input, i followed your way and only 0,25,200 show up. is that normal?